# SVG path not filling it's interior

Tags: svg

I have a svg image which has four paths which draw the perimeters of cuboid figures with curved corners.

I want to fill the interior of these figures. However, the fill="grey" property I am using on the path does not work.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 40" x="0px" y="0px" fill="grey">
   <path fill="grey" d="M5,14h6a3,3,0,0,0,3-3V5a3,3,0,0,0-3-3H5A3,3,0,0,0,2,5v6A3,3,0,0,0,5,14ZM4,5A1,1,0,0,1,5,4h6a1,1,0,0,1,1,1v6a1,1,0,0,1-1,1H5a1,1,0,0,1-1-1Z"/>
   <path d="M21,14h6a3,3,0,0,0,3-3V5a3,3,0,0,0-3-3H21a3,3,0,0,0-3,3v6A3,3,0,0,0,21,14ZM20,5a1,1,0,0,1,1-1h6a1,1,0,0,1,1,1v6a1,1,0,0,1-1,1H21a1,1,0,0,1-1-1Z"/>
   <path d="M2,27a3,3,0,0,0,3,3h6a3,3,0,0,0,3-3V21a3,3,0,0,0-3-3H5a3,3,0,0,0-3,3Zm2-6a1,1,0,0,1,1-1h6a1,1,0,0,1,1,1v6a1,1,0,0,1-1,1H5a1,1,0,0,1-1-1Z"/>
   <path d="M18,27a3,3,0,0,0,3,3h6a3,3,0,0,0,3-3V21a3,3,0,0,0-3-3H21a3,3,0,0,0-3,3Zm2-6a1,1,0,0,1,1-1h6a1,1,0,0,1,1,1v6a1,1,0,0,1-1,1H21a1,1,0,0,1-1-1Z"/>
</svg>
```

Any thoughts on what I need to do to fill in these cuboids?

Thanks

Comment: You're not defining just the perimeters in your path: you're defining both the outer and the inner border. So `fill:grey` is working as expected. Why aren't you using `rect` with corner radius?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your paths are filed grey. The problem is that there is a "hole" in in every path. I've removed the "hole

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 40" fill="grey">
   <path d="M5,14h6a3,3,0,0,0,3-3V5a3,3,0,0,0-3-3H5A3,3,0,0,0,2,5v6A3,3,0,0,0,5,14Z"/>
   <path d="M21,14h6a3,3,0,0,0,3-3V5a3,3,0,0,0-3-3H21a3,3,0,0,0-3,3v6A3,3,0,0,0,21,14Z"/>
   <path d="M2,27a3,3,0,0,0,3,3h6a3,3,0,0,0,3-3V21a3,3,0,0,0-3-3H5a3,3,0,0,0-3,3Z"/>
   <path d="M18,27a3,3,0,0,0,3,3h6a3,3,0,0,0,3-3V21a3,3,0,0,0-3-3H21a3,3,0,0,0-3,3Z"/>
</svg>
```